# Javascript if(condition) then addclass

Tags: javascript, if-statement, format, addclass

I'm trying to get a class added on when a div is inside a certain parent div.

```
<div class="parent1">
    <div class="child">
      Content
    </div>
</div>
```

.parent1 only exists on one page, while .child exists on others as well as this one.

So when .child is everywhere else, its color is red, but when it's inside .parent1 I want its color to be blue.

Here's what I'm using.

```
if ($('.child').parents('.parent1').length == 1) {
    .addClass('.new-class');
}
```

I'm having no success with this. Can anyone help?

Comment: If you used your Javascript console it would tell you about a syntax error.  `$('.child').addClass(...)`

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".parent1 .child").addClass("new-class");
```

Or

```
$(".parent1>.child").addClass("new-class");
```

If you want to make sure only first child will be populated with class:

```
<div class="parent1">
   <div class="child"> <!-- will have also "new-class" class -->
      <div class="child"> <!-- will NOT have "new-class" class -->
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! You have all been very helpful

Answer (score 0):

`.addClass('.new-class');` adds that class to *something*. You forgot to tell jQuery what *something* is, and caused a syntax error instead (which your browser console would have told you about if you had it open). I believe you want this:

```
$('.parent1 .child').addClass('.new-class');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you did tag this as just javascript...

HTML

```
<div class="parent1" id="parent">
    <div class="child" id="child">
      Content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.has-parent {
    color: blue;
}
```

Javascript

```
var child = document.getElementById('child');
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
if (child.parentNode == parent) {
    child.className += ' has-parent';
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/A47Jy/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this with just CSS:

```
.child
{
    color: red;
}
.parent .child
{
    color: blue;
}
```

So long as the `.parent .child` rule comes after the single `.child` rule, it will override the color with blue.  No extra work to change the color.  If you need this extra class for some other reason the The User 518469 's answer is probably best.